# Run-time error 2147023170 (800706be) when send messge from Excel to WhatsApp Desktop app

Tags: excel, vba

I used the below code for sending messages from Excel to WhatsApp desktop app it was perfectly working but suddenly I got the error mentioned in the subject and in the debug highlight the below line. I think there is some update in windows due to that in some computers we are getting problem. Please help

**IE.navigate strPostData**

""

```
Sub TextOnly()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim strip As String
Dim strPhoneNumber As String
Dim strMessage As String
Dim strPostData As String
Dim IE As Object
Dim TimeInterval As String
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
TimeInterval = "00:00:" & Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 8).Value
For i = 2 To LastRow    
    strPhoneNumber = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
    strMessage = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value
        
       
        strPostData = "whatsapp://send?phone=" & strPhoneNumber & "&text=" & strMessage
        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        IE.navigate strPostData
        
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(TimeInterval))
        
        Call SendKeys("{ENTER}", True)

Next i

End Sub
```

""

Comment: Are you really referring to "WhatsApp Desktop app" or Web WhatsApp?

Comment: IE is getting obsolete sometimes. Did you check if it works manually? Maybe is an outdate problem?